# How to filter on RAW data type oracle

Tags: oracle

We are using `Oracle` for one of our client databases. I am not very well versed with it. There is a column basis on which I need to filter records. The column was printing `System.Byte` before and when I converted it to VARCHAR(50) it was printing as `000B000000000000000000000000000A`.

I need to know how to filter the records with this value in the mentioned column.

Comment: Could you provide same sample data and expect results?

Answer (score 0):

If the idea of the column is to represent a hex string:

```
SELECT UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR ('000B000000000000000000000000000A', 'AL32UTF8')
  FROM DUAL;
```

could work for you, however more information about the application and expected results will be needed for a more fitting solution.